# Twilio Error 12100 with a well formed XML

Tags: xml, twilio

I followed the [Twilio QuickStarted Tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk/get-started) to run an Android App and communicate through a PHP server.

When I finished all steps, the app make the call but there is a voice explaining "We are sorry, an application error was ocurr."

Twilio portal debugger section says that the problem is that the "Document parse failure", but it IS well-formed (apparently, of course). I paste it below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<head/>
<Response>
    <Say>Congratulations! You have just made your first call! Good bye.</Say>
</Response>
```

If you want to check my server response you can access [here](http://52.59.223.68/makeCall.php).

Could someone help me find the problem? Thank you in advance.

UPDATE

As you guys said, the problem could be the  tag, however, even if I hardcore the response XML message, the server adds this tag between my response.

My server script:

```
print "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Response><Dial>+34 666 666 666</Dial><Say>Congratulations! You have just made your first call! Good bye.</Say></Response>";
```

The Twilio error:

> Message Text
>
> Msg   ""
>
> parserMessage "Error on line 1 of document : The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. "
>
> ErrorCode "12100"
>
> LogLevel  "ERROR"
>
> url   "http://52.59.223.68//makeCall.php"
>
> Body

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<head/>
<Response>
    <Dial>+34 666 666 666</Dial>
    <Say>Congratulations! You have just made your first call! Good bye.</Say>
</Response>
```

Comment: *but it IS well-formed*:   No, it isn't:  An XML document may only have a single root element; yours has two.

Comment: Has this ever been resolved? I have a similar issue and Twilio support has been in a circular loop about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The tag, <head/>, is not a valid TwiML XML tag. Remove that and you should be all set.

Comment: Apart from validation, the XML is not well-formed because it has two root elements; there may be only one.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is that i don't create the message, is the Twilio object: 

$response = new Twilio\Twiml();
if (!isset($to) || empty($to)) {
  $response->say('Congratulations! You have just made your first call! Good bye.');
print $response;

But even if I hardcore the return message without the **</head>** tag it doesn't works. The error is the same.